# Appcelerator titanium alloy build error build fail CopySwiftLibs

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I a developing a mobile app and i am getting this build error when try to launch the app on ios simulator. Much appreciate that if someone can help me figure this out.

[ERROR] ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] The following build commands failed:
[ERROR]         CopySwiftLibs /Users/shenalvanderwall/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/appforusers/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appforusers.app
[ERROR] (1 failure)

Process exited with 1

app was perfectly running till yesterday.

Comment: A bit more information is needed: Titanium SDK version, iOS version, XCode version. It might just be a OSX update that was running the day before or your XCode changed. Try reopening Xcode to see if all simulators are still there and run `ti clean` in your project to clean everything before building. Also use `--log-level trace` when building the app and check if there are more infos above that error

Comment: Hi @miga, I figured it. The problem was with the Titanium SDK. I downgraded it from 9.3 to 9.1.
Now it is working

Comment: that is a workaround but it should also work with the latest SDK! If you need further help feel free to post again, join TiSlack or the github discussions in the titanum_mobile repo

Comment: @miga Much appreciate the invitation. Will you be able to share me a url to find TiSlack and Github discussions?

Comment: sorry, of course: https://tislack.org/signup and https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/discussions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it. The problem was with the Titanium SDK. I downgraded it from 9.3 to 9.1.
Now it is working. The error was Titanium SDK was damaged somehow.